EFCore related entity not saved
I have an EFCore setup where in a class, I have a navigation property. As far as I can tell I followed the examples from microsoft to the dot, yet my added entity is not persisted. The setup is as follows. The summary is: I set up everything as the documentation suggests, yet when I try to save the Aggregate root, I get an error saying "expected 1 row to be affected but 0 were affected". After a lot of digging through the past few days, I found that while the dbContext identifies the navigation property field as being modified, it does not identify the Aggregate root as identified. My suspicion is that due to this, the aggregate root is not updated, and my SaveChagesAsync fails silently. I am completelly stuck as to what I am doing wrong at this point. I am using .NET 8.0.4 right now, as far as I'm aware it could also be a bug in the latest versions since I did have a similar setup a couple of weeks back work perfectly fine.
I have a DataSheet class, which is an Aggregate root entity. In this class, I have a list of categories, which is set up with a private backing field and a public IReadOnlyCollection, going by the examples from Ardalis's repositories.
public class DataSheet: Aggregate<Guid>
{
    
    private readonly List<Category> _categories = new();
    public IReadOnlyCollection<Category> Categories => _categories.AsReadOnly();
    
    .... more code here 



   public void CreateCategory(string name)
   {
       var orderIndex = (uint)_categories.Count;
       var category = new Category(name);
    
    _categories.Add(category);
   }
}

The Category class, is an entity which belongs to the DataSheet aggregate, and has a simple structure.
public class Category: Entity<Guid>
{
    public string Name { get; init; }
    
    private Category() { }
    
    public Category(string name): base(Guid.NewGuid())
    {
        Name = name;
    }
}

I have set the navigation property access mode to be a field, just like in the microsoft documentation:
public class DataSheetConfiguration: IEntityTypeConfiguration<DataSheet>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<DataSheet> builder)
    {
        builder.HasKey(b => b.Id);
       
        var categoryNavigation = builder.Metadata.FindNavigation(nameof(DataSheet.Categories));
        categoryNavigation.SetPropertyAccessMode(PropertyAccessMode.Field);
        
    }
}

And the CategoryConfigration:
public class CategoryConfiguration: IEntityTypeConfiguration<Category>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Category> builder)
    {
        builder.HasKey(c => c.Id);
        builder.Property(c => c.Name);
    }
}

Then in my DataContext I add these configurations:
public class DataContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    ... other DbSets
    public DbSet<DataSheet> DataSheets { get; set; } = null!;
    public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; } = null!;
        
    public DataContext() { }
    public DataContext(DbContextOptions<DataContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }
    
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        
        modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new DataSheetConfiguration());
        modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new CategoryConfiguration());
    }
}

Now, in my Appplication layer, when I try to add a new category using the repository SaveChangesAsync function, I get an error saying that it was expected that 1 row would be affected, but that in reality 0 rows were affected.
var spec = new CompleteDataSheet(request.DataSheetId);
        var sheet = await _dataSheetService.GetAsync(spec, cancellationToken);
        sheet.CreateCategory(request.Name);
        await _dataSheetService.UpdateAsync(sheet, cancellationToken);

public sealed class CompleteDataSheet: Specification<DataSheet>
{
    public CompleteDataSheet(Guid id)
    {
        Query
            .Where(b => b.Id == id)
            .Include(b => b.Categories);
    }
}

Here, the spec is defined to get the DataSheet by it's id and include the Categories items. The GetAsync succeeds in getting the sheet, and the Categories list is empty. After calling the CreateCategory, a new item shows in the Categories list. To persist my changes I then call the UpdateAsync function, which uses the repository to persist the changes.
When I went through the code from Ardalis.Specification package and the RepositoryBaseOfT class in the EntityFrameworkCore library, I see the error, however it otherwise fails silently.


After a lot of digging, I found that while the Categories field in the dbContext has a state of "Modified", the DataSheet entity has a state of Unchanged. When I forcefully set all the items in the Categories to a state of "Added" by itterating through it and programatically changing the state, then the new items get persisted. This however is not an solution from a design perspective.
Previously I had a navigation property work fine, however in that use case, all the items in the list were being initialized on the entity initialization, and they only got updated, not added new instances.
What is wrong in my setup that does not allow the DataSheet aggregate to detect the items in it's collection as changed or added and persist them?

Why do you call Update explicitly? It is not needed and has performance impact if entity already tracked.

Because I need to save the changes that I made to the DataSheet aggregate

If entity ALREADY tracked, this call is not needed. EF has problem with saving related entities when entity is attached. You have not shown whole saving process.

I added the part of code for that, in my applycation layer I use a service class which gets the sheet by id. After that the CreateCategory is called and the sheet state is as I expect, it has a new category item inside the Categories list. After calling the UpdateAsync on the service, which calls the UpdateAsync of the repository, the data is not persisted.

Well, you have created a lot of services without knowing how EF Core works. _dataSheetService.GetAsync(spec, cancellationToken) should Include Categories. Then Categories will be tracked and adding item to Categories should be handled. Update call should be avoided.

That's not the case, but I should have been more through. I added the code for the spec. Like I mentioned before, the categories ARE included, inside of the spec instance. There you can see that it gets the sheet by Id, and then includes the Categories

Start from making it work without hiding everything from EF Core and users. Use ICollection, use simple properties. Then one by one try to fix protection issues.

I also tried with an ICollection, and IEnumerator and the same issue persisted.

I also tried as you suggested, to not use the UpdateAsync of the repository and call just the SaveChangesAsync but with the same result

I believe you are missing 'categoryNavigation.SetField("_categories");For binding to a backing collection. Not sure if you can easily do away with the magic string. And no,Updateshould not be used in your case, it is intended for detached entities, not tracked ones. If you want the DbContext completely abstracted then you should check if the entity is tracked first.Set.Local.Any(x => x == entity);before resorting toUpdate`. (Which will be potentially complicated when it comes to updating detached entity graphs)

I'm not sure that is actually needed, unless the naming is different. I read and can confirm that there is an automatic name resolution following the "_camelCase" notation. Regardless, I did try and specify the SetField, and as well use the SaveAsync instead of Updated, even though the Update is from the EFCore repository base and that already does a Set.Update(entity). Still did not fix the issue

I have found another interesting thing. If I update a base parameter from the DataSheet and save it, the change is persisted as expected, however, if I also now add the Category, to the list of categories, the sheet is no longer changed and I get the DbUpdateConcurencyException. It seems that somehow the relationship breaks everything. This is also using a relationship that has no navigation property, so a simple HasMany configuration.

First of all, just use a property without backing fields and without an expression body.
public class DataSheet: Aggregate<Guid>
{
    public ICollection<Category> Categories { get; init; }
}

And your Category Entity like this:
public class Category: Entity<Guid>
{
    public string Name { get; init; }
 
    public DataSheet DataSheet { get; init; }
    
    public Guid DataSheetId { get; init; }
}

Then you don´t need these lines at all, because EF will automatically detect the Navigation Properties:
var categoryNavigation = builder
       .Metadata
       .FindNavigation(nameof(DataSheet.Categories));

categoryNavigation.SetPropertyAccessMode(PropertyAccessMode.Field);


I am using DDD design. A property without a backing field is not acceptable in this case, as it makes the list modifiable from the exterior. The idea behind having the backing field is so that only the owning class modifies the list

Ok, I see. What about adding and setting the foreign Key DataSheetId (as I showed in my post) to the DataSheet Guid. This way EF "knows" that this category belongs to the specific DataSheet (1-n relationship) and should do the trick.

That is also a violation. The category item has no business knowing anything about the DataSheet and should not have any code that is a database concern. The approach of DDD design is for the domain models to have as much as possible only code that is relevant for the business logic. Having the datasheetId inside the Category is purelly a database concern and polutes the domain model. Additionally it is not necessary

Its necessary for EF to detect your changes :) I know DDD, but EF Core has some conventions, that you have to follow or you have to find workarounds, like in your case.

I don't think it is necessary because I have a similar setup on a different data type, in the same DataSheet class, where this worked fine before, without the foreign key reference

Something is still broken and we have to go through it. Have you tried to set the Relation explicitly -  because again - I still think, that EF does not recognize this 1-n relationship. You could do that like this: builder.HasMany(e => e.Catagories).WithOne(e => e.DataSheet). But that still needs an Navigation property on the other side of the relation.

I did actually, I set it to be like you suggested. I tried both with just the relationship and with the navigation property. But the result was the same. The DataSheet was perceived as unchanged and the tne category was not saved. The only thing that I found to work, was to manually go through the categories from the dbContext, and set their state forcefully to Added. That ended up persisting in the database.

I have found the reason for this bug and it is caused by the way the Id of the Category is created. In my Category class posted in the question, I show that it inherits from a base Entity class, and on construction, it generates it's own Guid value. This however was not reflected in the CategoryConfiguration, where the Id was specified as key, but it was not set to be .ValueGeneratedNever().
Because this was lacking, EFCore expects then that any new item should have an id of default value and then it would add it. Given that my entity was coming with an already existing Id, efcore then interprets this as being an update operation, however, since the object is not yet present in the database, then it will fail silently but without giving an error saying that it could not find any object with that Id.
Changing the CategoryConfiguration to say that the Id property is .ValueGeneratedNever has fixed everything. Including the navigation property. Unfortunatelly if there would be a more informative error message this would have been solved sooner. Luckly I remembered that I had to do this to the other relationship which I kept referencing and gave it a try.
